# Angular $routeProvider without hash (#)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I have a `$routeProvider` in my angular app, for different paths, here is how it looks:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
     title: 'Main',
   })
   .when('/howItWorks', {
      templateUrl: 'views/hiw.html',
      controller: 'HiwCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'hiw',
      title: 'How it works'
    })
    ...
```

In this case, when I go to `/#howItWorks`, it will load the `HiwCtrl` and its view.

Now I have an url that looks like `/users` without the hash at the begin. How can I modify this to support both urls?

Comment: Is your project based only on angular ?

Comment: yes, it starts with `connect` server of node, with grunt

Comment: At the moment I didn't find any straightforward implementation using just provided stuff by angular, the problem is that your hash will be removed by angular parsing algorithm, so we need to change that but at the moment I am not sure if this is possible without affecting the angular vendor. only I now after event $locationChangeStart the route parse will be triggered. I will search for more and will replay if will find something

Answer (score 6):

If any question just read more about html5Mode in the official angularjs documentation.

```
app.config(['$locationProvider',function($locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

});
```

Comment: but wont this modify for all urls? I just need one url to be parsed like this

Comment: If you need for specific urls just add a hash to the begginning of the when like so: .when('/#howItWorks'

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 app.config([  '$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',  
   function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {  
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({  
   enabled: true,  
   requireBase: false  
 }).hashPrefix('!');  

$routeProvider  
 .when('/home', { // For Home Page  
   templateUrl: 'Home.html',  
   controller: 'HomeController'  
  })       
 .otherwise({  // This is when any route not matched => error  
   controller: 'ErrorController'  
 })  
 }]);
```